# 'The power is out' vs 'The power has gone out'

Tags: grammaticality

Suppose a person is using an electrical appliance and suddenly there is a power outage- would it be correct if that person immediately said to their family members that 'the power is out'? Or would it be better to say 'power has gone out'?

In what way are they different? Are both idiomatic?

(And similarly, is there a distinction between 'the power has come back' and 'the power is back on'?)

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable.  It's a question of emphasis and tense.

> The power is out.

This refers to it being out right now.

> The power has gone out.

This refers to the event, in the past, of the power stopping. Usually this will be said when the interruption happened quite recently, and is still going on.

Comment: You can also say "The power has gone out several times this week."

Comment: What about 'The power has been out'? Does it mean the same as 'The power has gone out'?